# Codeigniter looping inside another loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Main product category Listed Like

1. Cake
2. List item
3. Bun
4. Toffees
5. Bread

Under one Main product category there are sub products too.

1 Cake 
 (1.1 Butter Cake)(1.2 Chocolate cake)

On my view I echo these main Products only by using following code.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
            <div class="span2">
                <p class="text-center subheader"><?php echo $row->main_products_cat_name; ?>
                </p>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>product/all_product_data?id=<?php echo $row->main_products_cat_id;?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assests/images/products/main_products/<?php echo $row->main_products_cat_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->main_products_cat_name; ?>" width="200px" height="200px">
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>          
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Can some one help me to echo Sub product category under Main Product.

Comment: can you show us the table(s) and the query that you used to get the $records from ? the question is not clear , in your $records , we can only understand that you have the main category id and image, do you have all the subcategories inside it too ? we don't know, so the database schema and the used query should be a part of the question, and then you will have an answer for sure !

Comment: @Baci it's not hard to use commented pseudo fields

Comment: @charlietfl what's a commented pseudo fields ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I assume that your category table looks like this

```
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | tinyint(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| parent_id | tinyint(4) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| name      | varchar(255)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| note      | varchar(254)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

notice that you have a recursive relationship (parent_id pointing to id)

now, let's populate it with some data like this

```
+----+-----------+----------------+------+
| id | parent_id | name           | note |
+----+-----------+----------------+------+
|  1 | NULL      | bakery         | NULL |
|  2 |         1 | Cake           | NULL |
|  3 |         1 | Bun            | NULL |
|  4 |         1 | Toffee         | NULL |
|  5 |         1 | Bread          | NULL |
|  6 |         2 | Chocolate cake | NULL |
|  7 |         2 | Butter cake    | NULL |
|  8 |         3 | Honey bun      | NULL |
|  9 |         5 | Italian bread  | NULL |
| 10 |         5 | French bread   | NULL |
| 11 |         5 | Bereber bread  | NULL |
+----+-----------+----------------+------+
```

so now we create a method in the model that gets all the subcategories of a given id

**Model**

```
<?php
class menu_mdl extends CI_Model
{

        public function get_subcategories_id($id)
        {
            $qry_str = "SELECT
            categories.id,
            categories.`name` AS name
            FROM
            categories
            WHERE
            categories.parent_id = ".$id;
            $q = $this->db->query($qry_str);
            return $q->result();            
        }
}
?>
```

then we call this method in the controller menu.php as so

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class menu extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("menu_mdl");
         // get all the subcategories of the root category with id = 1
        $all_categories_id = $this->menu_mdl->get_subcategories_id(1);

        // prepare the menu as an HTML string  
        $menu = "<ul>";
        //loop through level1 then level2 then level3... you can go as many levels as you want!
        foreach($all_categories_id as $level1)
        {
            if($level1->id)
            {
                $menu .= "<li><a href='#'>".$level1->name."</a></li>"; 
                $sub_level1 = $this->menu_mdl->get_subcategories_id($level1->id);
                if ($sub_level1)
                {
                    $menu .= "<ul>";
                    foreach($sub_level1 as $level2)
                    {
                        $menu .= "<li><a href='#'>".$level2->name."</a></li>";
                        $sub_level2 = $this->menu_mdl->get_subcategories_id($level2->id);
                        if ($sub_level2)
                        {
                            $menu = "<ul>";
                            foreach($sub_level2 as $level3)
                            {
                                $menu .= "<li><a href='#'>".$level3->name."</a></li>";
                            }
                            $menu .= "</ul>";   
                        } 
                    }
                    $menu .= "</ul>";
                }
            }   

        }
        $menu .= "</ul>"; 

        $data["menu"] = $menu; // <--- this variable has all the menu as HTML string
        $this->load->view('menu',$data);
    }


}
```

now in the view we just echo the ready menu by a simple echo like that

**view**

```
<?php 
echo $menu ; 
?>
```

then the output will look like this

```html
<ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Cake</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Chocolate cake</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Butter cake</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Bun</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Honey bun</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Toffee</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Bread</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Italian bread</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>French bread</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Bereber bread</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

that's all there is to it

---

**update** 
you can use this **controller** instead of the previous one, if you want (thanks to Meh for the idea about the recursive function) , to loop through all the subcategories until the last child using a function magix (because it's magic :p )

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class menu extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("menu_mdl");
         // get all the subcategories of the root category with id = 1
        $all_categories_id = $this->menu_mdl->get_subcategories_id(1);

        // prepare the menu as an HTML string  
        $menu = "<ul>";
        //loop through level1 then level2 then level3... you can go as many levels as you want!
        foreach($all_categories_id as $level1)
        {
            // loop until through subcategories until there is no subcategories 
            $this->magix($level1,$menu);
        }
        $menu .= "</ul>"; 

        $data["menu"] = $menu; // <--- this variable has all the menu as HTML string
        $this->load->view('menu',$data);
    }

    private function magix($level_id,&$menu)
    {
        if($level_id->id)
            {
                $menu .= "<li><a href='#'>".$level_id->name."</a></li>"; 
                $sub_level = $this->menu_mdl->get_subcategories_id($level_id->id);
                if ($sub_level)
                {
                    $menu .= "<ul>";
                    foreach($sub_level as $level2)
                    {
                        $menu .= "<li><a href='#'>".$level2->name."</a></li>";
                        $sub_level2 = $this->menu_mdl->get_subcategories_id($level2->id);
                        if ($sub_level2)
                        {
                            $this->magix($level_id,$menu);  
                        } 
                    }
                    $menu .= "</ul>";
                }
            }   
    }

}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: better to make a function to get subcategories and in that function say if it has sub, then call the same function to get subs. It makes an unlimited level category listing.

Comment: @meh yes that's what get_subcategories_id($id) does in the model  and in the controller it just checks if there is a child and puts it in the $menu , or did I miss understood you ?

Comment: Look at toUL() function in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I share my own get_category() method. The idea is not mine. I got it from somewhere I don't remember about a year ago.

```
public static $list;
public static function get_category(){
        $map_result = Product::get_category_array();
        // it's like select * from categories. with your table structure

        foreach($map_result as $row){
            $ref = &$refs[$row['cat_id']];

            $ref['parent_id'] = $row['parent_id'];
            $ref['cat_name']  = $row['cat_name'];
            $ref['cat_id']  = $row['cat_id'];

            if ($row['parent_id'] == 0){
                $list[$row['cat_id']] = &$ref;
            }else{
                $refs[$row['parent_id']]['children'][$row['cat_id']] = &$ref;
            }
        }
        self::$list = $refs;

        function toUL($list){
            $class="";
            $html = "";

            foreach ($list as $value){
                if (!empty($value['children'])){
                    $html .= '<li><a class="dir" href="./index.php?cat='.$value['cat_id'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($value['cat_name'])."</a>";
                }else{
                    $html .= '<li><a href="./index.php?cat='.$value['cat_id'].'">'.htmlspecialchars($value['cat_name'])."</a>";
                }

                if (!empty($value['children'])){
                    $html .= "<ul>".toUL($value['children'])."</ul>";
                }
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
            return $html;
        }
        return toUL($list);
    }
```

Look at toUL function and how it's been used inside of it for a recursive listing.

Comment: that looks a bit complicated to me, how would I implement it with my solution , Im kinda scratching my head right now lol

Comment: @Baci The benefit of this code is that it uses 1 query to get categories then sort it in a recursive array then echo it. You can forget about the first part which is sorting in array. Just for outputting, take your first `foreach()` to a function forexample name it abc($id) then after `if ($sub_level)`, use that abc($new_id) to get rest of categories and put it into a variable for echo. It might be a new solution but ur code works fine and it's just an improvement.

Comment: take a look  :) I got inspired, using a recursive function like a man ! lol